# How to implement TypeScript class with property as a class in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, typescript, knockout.js

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm starting to learn how to use knockout.js with TypeScript and how to create a viewmodel with knockout.js. It's just a simple example trying to understand basic class inside a module, and right know I'm able to create a data-bind with the `Client` class, it's working correctly the `name` and `lastName`, but I have a C# context, so in C# you can create a class like a property inside a class

For example in C# you can create a class like this, creating a property with class `Activity`

```
public class Client 
{
    public string ClientName {get;set;}
    public Activity Activity {get;set;}
}

public class Activity
{
    public string ActivityName {get;set;}
}


//And call this like c# but with typescript sort of
Client client = new Client();
client.Activity = new Activity();
client.Activity.ActivityName = "Activity name";
```

So I want to reproduce something like that with typescript and knockout. So this is what I'm trying but it's not working the `activity` "class" I can't get it's properties and methods.

```
module Crm {
    export class Client {
        name: KnockoutObservable<string>;
        lastName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
        activity: KnockoutObservable<Activity>;
        getName() {
            return alert(this.name()); //working correctly on the view
        }
        //constructor(name:string, lastName:string) {
        constructor(){
            this.name = ko.observable("");
            this.lastName = ko.observable("");
            this.activity = ko.observable(new Activity());
        }
    }

    export class Activity {
        id: KnockoutObservable<number>;
        names: KnockoutObservable<string>;
        description: KnockoutObservable<string>;
        date: KnockoutObservable<any>;
        getActivityName() {
            return alert("Actividad: " + this.description()); //not working
        }
        constructor() {
            this.id = ko.observable(0);
            this.names = ko.observable("");
            this.description = ko.observable("");
            this.date = ko.observable("");
        }
    }

    var a = new Client();
    console.log(a);
    ko.applyBindings(new Client());
}
```

And here it's the simple html I'm testing

```
<p>First name: <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: name" /> </p> 
<p>Last name: <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: lastName" /></p> 

<button data-bind="click: getName">Get name</button> <!-- working correctly -->
<hr />

<p>Activity</p>
<input type="text" data-bind="activity().description" /> <!-- not working -->

<button data-bind="click: activity().getActivityName">Try me</button> <!-- this click data-bind it's probably wrong, I'm trying to understand how to call the activity method and parameters -->

<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/client.js"></script>
```

The client it's working, but the activity isn't. I don't know if I'm trying this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding context for the `getActivityName` is `Client` object, hence you have wrong `this` object.

1. The current bound model is passed to a click function as a first argument.

You can check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgf0jtLd/3/) with fixed code:

```
getActivityName(client: Client) {
    return alert("Actividad: " + client.activity().description());
}
```

2. You can also change current binding context via `with` binding:

```

```
<!-- ko with: activity -->
<input type="text" data-bind="description" />

<button data-bind="click: getActivityName">Try me</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

```

You can see this approach in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsko7sn8/2/).

Comment: Yeah both methods are working correctly, I know it was something about the "this" with the first approach.